# Adding hidden input element in display tag

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

How can I have additional html elements in display tag?

```
<display:table name="list" pagesize="3">
    <display:column property="name" title="NAME"/>
</display:table>
```

I want the column name with a hidden input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<display:table name="list" pagesize="3" id="row">
    <display:column title="NAME">
         <input type="hidden" name="..."> 
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

You cannot mix with using the `property` attribute in `display:column`, but having added the id="row" you can now access the "row" object inside the element, like:

```
<% ((YourRowBean)row ).getName() %>
```

or

```
${row.name}
```